# Java EE7/Glassfish Update Tool does not show up

Tags: netbeans, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I'm trying to do the Java EE 7 tutorials on my Windows 7 laptop.

To use the tutorial, you have to run the Update Tool.  You can run the Update Tool either by right-clicking on Glassfish 4 under Servers in the Services section of NetBeans.  Or you can get to it using Start>All Programs>Java EE 7 SDK>Start Update Tool.  I've tried it both ways and I get the same result, even after going through the process of telling NetBeans to install the Update Tool: The cursor shows the computer thinking, and then... nothing.  Nothing at all happens.

Can anyone help me figure out why the Update Tool isn't opening?

Answer (score 7):

I tried a few things: installing an older version of Glassfish (v.3), but that didn't work.  Then I reinstalled version 4.  Still didn't work.  But then I found another path to the Update Tool.  If you start the server and then right-click Glassfish again and choose View Domain Admin Console, look down on the very bottom left side of the screen and you'll see another link to the Update Tool.  For some reason, THIS one worked!

Comment: I had the same issue, and using your method fixed it. Thanks a lot for sharing.

Comment: Thank you for sharing :) it has been bugging me a lot that I couldn't reach the update tool from netbeans. What do you reckon could be the cause of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to localhost:4848. This is the default port,so if you changed it, used the one you've entered.